# Way to view all symbols/files in a given VC++ exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to find a way to view all the symbols included in a given solution's executable.

Ideally, I'd like to end up with a tab delimited list of symbol to file, with the namespaces.  Dependencies would be nice also.

The goal is to find mismatched namespaces, as well as ensure code is deadstripped in release.

As a reference, Flash Builder + eclipse had a nifty linker option that would list all symbols and their dependencies.  It was really useful to find the 'sticky' points of linking.

I tried looking for a pdb viewer or command line option, but there doesn't seem to be anything out there.  Does anyone know a way to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on "mismatched namespaces?"

Comment: Such a tool would make your eyes bleed for anything but very trivial programs.  You can easily write one yourself with the DbgHelp api.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @JohnDibling - mainly for our project- we have some classes that are have no namespace or in platform specific namespaces that should be in a common platform-less namespace

Comment: @HansPassant - can you elaborate on the bleeding?  A lot of output isn't a big deal; the flash compiler would easily spit out a meg or two of text.  At that point it was just a matter of filtering by file/class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon the feature I was looking for.

It's under Linker->Debugging->Generate Map File & Map File Name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dumpbin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c.aspx), which is similar to objdump but for windows.

Comment: I tried using dumpbin earlier, but no combination of parameters got any symbol output.  Is there a combination of arguments you know of that would achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using cdb.exe. Here's an example output:

```
PS C:\Users\jyn\src\example> & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\cdb.exe" -c "x normal!; q" normal.exe | select -first 13
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command 'x normal!; q'
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for normal.exe
00007ff6`5e0cb2c8 normal!__guard_xfg_dispatch_icall_fptr = 0x00007ff6`5e0c9a80
00007ff6`5e0d50b0 normal!_fltused = 0n39029
00007ff6`5e0d5278 normal!__scrt_current_native_startup_state = uninitialized (0n0)
00007ff6`5e0d0a10 normal!_tls_end = 0n0 ''
00007ff6`5e0cb2e8 normal!__xc_a = <function> *[1]
00007ff6`5e0cb2e8 normal!__xc_a = <function> *[]
00007ff6`5e0d50f0 normal!__scrt_ucrt_dll_is_in_use = 0n1
00007ff6`5e0d50f0 normal!__scrt_ucrt_dll_is_in_use = 0n1
00007ff6`5e0cb310 normal!pre_c_initializer = 0x00007ff6`5e0c8e80
```

CDB is part of the Debugging Tools for Windows, which has installation instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools#install-debugging-tools-for-windows. You can see a full reference for the `x` command at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/x--examine-symbols-.